# May one soak bulgur wheat on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, melacha-creative-work, water

One method to make tabouleh, is to soak bulgur wheat in water. The method is to pur an amount of bulgur into a bowl, cover it with water and have it soak in the fridge for about 30 mins. until the water is absorbed. This softens the bulgur. No squeezing is done.

If I recall correctly, there is a problem with soaking things on Shabbat, and I seem to recall some prohibition against soaking vegetables (or is it only pickling in brine?) on Shabbat. I also am pretty sure that there is a problem soaking your clothes (laundry? cleaning?) but I don't know if there is a problem soaking food in the manner prescribed.

Would there be a problem preparing tabouleh in this manner?

Comment: As far as pickling or salting vegetables on Shabbos, see [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=931).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rav cited the book "The Kosher Kitchen" (will edit in more details in a few days...)

It depends on the purpose of the soaking. If it is just to soften the bulgur, there is no problem, as the prohibition (melacha) of soaking applies just to clothes.

If the purpose is to cause the dirt, stones, or other grinds to float to the top, then there is a problem of "borer" (separating / sorting).